# php mysql 2 select to 1 select

Tags: php, mysql

```
id | cid | name 
 1 | 1   | product 1 
 2 | 1   | product 2 
 3 | 1   | product 3 
 4 | 1   | product 4 
 5 | 1   | product 5 
 6 | 1   | product 6 
 7 | 2   | product 7 
 8 | 2   | product 8
 9 | 2   | product 9 
10 | 2   | product 10 
11 | 2   | product 11 
12 | 2   | product 12 
13 | 3   | product 13 
14 | 3   | product 14
15 | 3   | product 15
16 | 3   | product 16
```

**PHP:**

```
$query  = "SELECT cid FROM product GROUP BY cid  ORDER by cid DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error()); 

echo 'id |cid | name  <br>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    list($cid) = $row;

    $query2  = "SELECT id, cid, name FROM product WHERE cid  = $cid ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_NUM)){
        list($id2, $cid2, $name2) = $row2;
        echo ''.$id2.' | '.$cid2.' | '.$name2.'  <br>';
    }   

}
```

**return ==>>**

```
id | cid | name 
16 | 3   | product 16 
15 | 3   | product 15 
14 | 3   | product 14 
12 | 2   | product 12 
11 | 2   | product 11 
10 | 2   | product 10 
 6 | 1   | product 6 
 5 | 1   | product 5 
 4 | 1   | product 4
```

**Now, i wan't 2 select to 1 select.**

example:

```
    $query  = "SELECT cid FROM product WHERE (SELECT id, cid, name FROM product WHERE cid  = $cid ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 3) GROUP BY cid  ORDER by cid DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        list($id, $cid, $name) = $row;
        echo ''.$id.' | '.$cid.' | '.$name.'  <br>';
    }
```

**return ==>>**

```
id | cid | name 

16 | 3   | product 16 
15 | 3   | product 15 
14 | 3   | product 14
12 | 2   | product 12 
11 | 2   | product 11 
10 | 2   | product 10 
 6 | 1   | product 6 
 5 | 1   | product 5 
 4 | 1   | product 4
```

**help me! thanks for support**

Comment: So want you want is, from a table with id, cid, name, you want to have max 3 rows for of each different cid.

Comment: yes, i want to have max 3 rows for of each different cid

Comment: But what is your question? Is your last query not working? Do you want to have it better?

Comment: Yes. I want one command instead of two

Comment: $query  = "SELECT cid FROM product WHERE (SELECT id, cid, name FROM product WHERE cid  = $cid ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 3) GROUP BY cid  ORDER by cid DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        list($id, $cid, $name) = $row;
        echo ''.$id.' | '.$cid.' | '.$name.'  <br>';
    }

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve it would be as

```
SELECT *
FROM   product p
WHERE (
  SELECT  COUNT(*) 
  FROM    product  p1
  WHERE p1.cid = p.cid AND 
  p.id <= p1.id
) <= 3
order by p.id desc
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93be7/10)**

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It has run

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution without using procedures...

What is done here is SUBSTRING_INDEX is being used to limit the entries used by GROUP_CONCAT.

And the result of GROUP_CONCAT is used as a set to be searched by FIND_IN_SET.

```
SELECT
    p1.*
FROM
    products p1
    inner join (
        SELECT
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p2.id SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) AS ids
        FROM
            products p2
        GROUP BY
            p2.cid
    ) AS ids
        ON FIND_IN_SET(p1.id, ids.ids)
ORDER BY
    p1.cid DESC,
    p1.id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ecf4/8/0)

PS:

You won't u run into this now, but just be aware: GROUP_CONCAT has a maximum length setting (as in characters length of a string) that sets what the GROUP_CONCAT can return. This is 1024 characters by default, and thus is sufficient for 3 INT ids because each INT id with adjending comma is max 12 characters. If you go extreme and want more than 85 records *per cid*, you will need to adjust your mysql `group_concat_max_len` setting.

Comment: Error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @user1910602 yeah, my bad. I just changed and fixed my answer